# "express one's stance for" VS "express one's stand for"

Tags: word-difference

> 1. They expressed its ***stance*** for the Copenhagen Accord.
> 2. They expressed its ***stand*** for the Copenhagen Accord.

My question is whether stance and stand are exchangable in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this sort of context *stand* and *stance* are not interchangeable.

Your *stand **for*** something expresses your active support of it. (Active opposition to it would be expressed as a *stand **against*** it.)

Your *stance **toward*** something expresses your attitude toward it, which may be positive or negative.

*Stance **for*** is encountered only where *stance* = "physical posture" — for instance, *the proper stance for a drive* in golf.

Comment: You mean only "express one's stand for something" is legitimate?  "express one's stance for" does not make sense, right? @stoneyB

Comment: @MikePhilip You got it.